# Unable to use git from Powershell 7.1 in Windows 10

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, powershell-7.0

I installed Git for Windows and Powershell 7.1. When I try to clone a repository from git bash using ssh key, it works perfectly. However when I try to do similar from Powershell 7.1, I get a **fatal: Could not read from remote repository** error.

**Steps Followed**

```
1. PS> Start-Service ssh-agent
2. PS> ssh-add D:\Keys\.ssh\my_private_key (I get identity added message)
3. PS> git clone git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git
```

**Error Message**

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Comment: I got the answer @phd. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means ssh, in that Powershell session, is trying to look for SSH keys at `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `D:\Keys`

Check in your git bash if you have a `~/.ssh/config` file which would specify the right private key to use for `Host github.com`.
And check what `~` (that is `echo $HOME`) resolves in said `git bash` session.
If should not be the same as the default HOME in a Powershell session, where git defaults to `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: Thanks - copying my id_rsa file to C:\Users\username\.ssh\ did the trick!

Comment: Now the question is, is there a way to make Powershell use the key file kept somewhere, instead of using the one in %USERPROFILE%?

Comment: Yes, you can use a similar config file to specify the private key path. Put the config file in the same folder you just used.